# My computer says "/dev/sda2 contains a file system with error, check forced" and shows this

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

Power goes off while I was using my PC and when i try to boot my PC it fails and says

```
/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

The full error picture is here..[image]

My OS is `Kali Linux`.

Comment: Did you run fsck as mentioned? The file system seems to be corrupted due to abrupt shut down.

Comment: No I didn't..can u help me with it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned, run this:

```
fsck /dev/sda2
```

And after the reboot it should be fine.

Comment: It worked straight, relief.